# Where's this landscape with a stream and rocks in Canada, from TourRadar's Canada Video?

Tags: canada, identify-this, photography, locate-this

Source: [10 mins 21 s](https://youtu.be/RUmAUnL65gU?t=10m21s) juncture.

[image]

Comment: To me it looks a lot like the South Saskatchewan River valley, somewhere in Western Saskatchewan or Eastern Alberta. But a bit of searching hasn't turned up a definite match yet;  I'll post a full answer if it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can confirm that this stunning view belongs to Milk River, near the border of Alberta and Montana. Paying a visit to Writing-on-Stone Provincial Park will provide you access to the river and the hundreds of Sandstone Hoodoos located in this impressive region of Canada.

- Katie from the TourRadar team

Comment: Welcome to Travel StackExchange!  It's always nice to get confirmation from "primary sources" on this sort of thing.