# Where's this in Writing-on-Stone Provincial Park, AB?

Tags: canada, identify-this, alberta

[image]

I saw this on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EenqPlRQX9A) with description -

> Grab your hiking boots and join photographers Alex Strohl (@alexstrohl) and Andrea Dabene (@andreadabene) along with hiking guide A.V Wakefield (@picobac) as they explore the natural beauty of Writing-on-Stone Provincial Park and Waterton Lakes National Park. (remember to breathe)

This doesn't look like Waterton. Thus where is this at Writing-on-Stone?

Comment: There is only one major waterway through the park, the Milk River, so I presume that's what's in view.  And the park is only 4 km wide, with a road near the river at most parts.  Do you really need a more specific location, and why?  I'm pretty sure that if you go to the park, you'll have no trouble finding that view, or one that looks very similar.

Comment: Related:  [Where's this landscape with a stream and rocks in Canada, from TourRadar's Canada Video?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104837/wheres-this-landscape-with-a-stream-and-rocks-in-canada-from-tourradars-canad/104909#104909)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same view (not the same image, but taken from the same location) is displayed in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing-on-Stone_Provincial_Park#/media/File:MilkriverAB.JPG) on Writing-on-Stone Provincial Park. That suggested the picture might have been taken from an easily accessible viewpoint.

Using Google Maps, I navigated to the central area of the Park, which is developed with some roads and basic visitor facilities. Google Street View wasn't available for the roadways, but some not-on-the-road photos were shown as available; they're marked in blue. The blue-lined track's shape looked like someone had taken the images while walking up a ridgeline. The pointed end of the track's little loop looked like a viewpoint.

Here's a screenshot of Google Maps, with the blue line showing, and the likely location of the photographer marked. [Go to this place on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Writing-on-Stone+Provincial+Park/@49.0850365,-111.6153589,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x536bec4126fb1cd7:0x43862d78b06e1f34!8m2!3d49.0858903!4d-111.6195612?hl=en&authuser=0), and click on the little orange figure button at the right-hand lower corner of the Google Maps window; the blue line track and other photo locations will appear. Then click on the place I've indicated, and you'll be taken to that point. There's a 360 degree view; turn so you're looking east, and you can see the same view as shown in the questioned picture.

[image: ![enter image description here]